# How to maintain a company domain list while implementing an official email ID verification feature

Tags: authentication

I want to display a verified badge on my app's user profile based on whether the user has verified their official company alias (to show increased credibility). Is there any third-party service to achieve this? Or manually maintaining a list of company names is the only way?